# Internet Explorer 11 and up: toggles on click interactivity in pure SVG?

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, internet-explorer-11

Is it possible, when working with pure SVG (no Javascript et cetera), to have a user, on Internet Explorer 11 and up (without any further browser plug-ins) **click** on one part of an SVG, and to thus toggle the visibility of another part of the SVG? If so, could you please create a MWE that demonstrate the possibility? I have been browsing the web for hours, but couldn't find anything.

The end-purpose is uploading such a SVG to Wikimedia Commons (where Javascript is forbidden). There exists such files with regards to **hovering** (See some exmamples at https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Interactive_SVG), but as far as I know there exist no such file which does the same for **clicking**.

[Here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e2/London_Underground_Overground_DLR_Crossrail_map_alt.svg), for example is a file which does feature interactivity through **clicking**, but unfortunately it **does not work on Internet Explorer 11**.

Note: I am sorry I can not come up with a MWE myself, as of yet I haven't been able to find a clue on what technique to use.

Comment: Are you allowed to upload custom CSS?

Comment: @RyanWilson I am not sure what you mean? See for example [the linked file](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e2/London_Underground_Overground_DLR_Crossrail_map_alt.svg) in which there is a functional and allowed `<style type="text/css">`...`</style>` in the uploaded file.

Comment: <quote>This category shows interactive SVG files. The preview may be incomplete or incorrect. To use the interactive possibilities open it in an SVG Animation aware browser or viewer, e.g., Opera or Internet Explorer with Adobe SVG plugin. </quote> I don't think the AdobeSVG plugin ActiveX control is supported in IE11 or Opera (webkit) any more.(since IE9)

Answer (score 1):

This will not be feasible.

The requirement obviously involves changing svg attributes in response to user actions. The [SVG specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/Overview.html) have a subsection on [interactivity](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html) that details event support (list adapted from [subsection 16.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html#SVGEvents) from afore-mentioned specs):

- Registered event handlers ( n/a, JS implementation needed )
- Event attributes on elements in general ( n/a, JS implementation needed )
- Event attributes on animation elements

Animation elements define dynamic behavior in a declarative fashion (ie. without user coding) in accordance with the [SMIL specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/smil-animation/), in particular the [timing events](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-smil-animation-20010904/#Timing-EventValueSyntax). In fact, this is the method employed by the example [cited in the question](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e2/London_Underground_Overground_DLR_Crossrail_map_alt.svg).

Unfortunately, IE11's rendering engine [Trident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_(software)) fails here, [not supporting animation elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28Scalable_Vector_Graphics%29).

**Update**

[CSS animations](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-animations-1/) do not come to rescue here, as they are [not supported by IE 11 either](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46996587).

Anyway, AFAIK CSS animations do not provide a means to trigger them in response to user action without use of JS event handling.

Comment: So "pure" CSS solutions can also not provide any rescue?

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen There is a spec on [CSS animations](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-animations-1/) (also see [MDN on this topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)) . However, IE11 wouldn't support these either ( given the nascent nature of the specs would require backporting, MS probably isn't to blame on this one). Anyway, The issue is interactivity and AFAIK, CSS animations do not provide a means to trigger them in response to user action without use of JS event handling.

Comment: There are ways to achieve interactivity on clicks in pure CSS that work on Internet Explorer 11 (I have tested for example http://dabblet.com/gist/1506530 or https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gKJezv). My problem is: 1) Can they be integrated into a SVG, and 2) Can such an SVG still be uploaded to Wikimedia Commons and be functional.

Comment: @VincentMiaEdieVerheyen Nice one! Your technique hinges on built-in state changes reflected in css (pseudo)properties. I don't think that svg has an element similar to html's `input[checkbox]`, so i am still skeptical about a pure SVG solution. Inline svg, or perhaps html snippets includes as svg `foreignObject` content might work though, if the css trees are merged for the document (I don't know offhand whether thats the case).

Comment: Internet Explorer does not support foreignObject right, so I am in great despair. ;)